# Want to store page url to mysql using html form field

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have two `php` files. `index.php` and `insert.php`. I am inserting some data by using form but I also want to store the `index.php url` into `mysql` by using html form. Because I have many pages like `index.php` which are calling `insert.php`. Actually when some page call `insert.php` it should take the `url` of that page by using form so that i can store that `url` into database. Code is given below.

```
<?php

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","commentdb");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

// Everything is working fine but not taking the url
$sql="INSERT INTO comment (id, name, email,comment,url)
VALUES
(null, '$_POST[name]','$_POST[email]','$_POST[comment]', $_POST[url])";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }
echo "1 record added";

mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>My Comment Box</title>
</head>

<body>

<?php

//getURL function to get URL

function getURL()

 {

    /* First check if page is http or https */

    //$whichprotocol = $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on' ? 'https' : 'http';

    /* Combine different pieces of $_SERVER variable to return current URL */

    //return $whichprotocol.'://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    return '://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

 }

 /*Calling getURL function to display current page URL*/


?>



<form action="insert.php" method="post">

  <p>Name:
  <input name="name" type="text" />
  </p>
  <p>Email:
  <input name="email" type="text" />
  </p>
  <p>Comment:</p>
  <p>
    <textarea name="comment" cols="50" rows="10"></textarea>
  </p>
  <p>
    <--! getURL(); gives me error. It takes url but don't send it insert query -->
    <input type="hidden" name="url" id="url" value="<?php getURL();?>" />
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
  </p>
</form>
<br />
<?php
    echo getURL();
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `value="<?=getURL();?>"` or `value="<?php echo getURL();?>"` Did you try this?

Comment: as u_mulder is trying to say, your function is returning the value, but you are just calling the function. No where in there are you echo'ing that return value.

Comment: Why not just `<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];?>`?

Comment: Yes i echo it and it is echoing in current page but i don't want to echo. i want to store it in db by using some form element.

Comment: <--! getURL(); does not take url other values are submitting -->
    <input type="hidden" name="url" id="url" value="<?php getURL();?>" />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to echo the value from the function -

```
value="<?php echo getURL();?>" />
```

Comment: Thank you very much Sir! I am highly thankful to you.